# How is the expiryTime supposed to be used with SessionSecurityTokenCache.AddOrUpdate()?

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

I'm writing a custom implementation of [`SessionSecurityTokenCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159403.aspx) and I'm somewhat confused as to what the purpose of `expiryTime` is in the [AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokencache.addorupdate.aspx) method.

As far as I can tell, the default implementation for `SessionSecurityTokenCache` used by WIF is the internal class `MruSessionSecurityTokenCache` (mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545457.aspx)).  In its implementation, `expiryTime` is completely ignored.

Also, I notice while debugging that the value that gets passed in to `AddOrUpdate` appears to always be [`token.ValidTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytoken.validto.aspx) plus 5 minutes, so there is some intent to use this value somehow.

A few questions:

- What is the intended strategy for this value?

  - Occasional cache cleanup?
  - Should the `Get()` and `GetAll()` methods on `SessionSecurityTokenCache` be filtering out expired tokens?
- In any of these cases, why not just use `SessionSecurityToken.ValidTo` (or some offset therefrom)?

Comment: Hi Chris, did you ever figure out the purpose of expiryTime in AddOrUpdate? We are handling the SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived event to enable sliding sessions and in that method, SessionSecurityToken.ValidTo does not match the expiryTime of the TokenCacheItem we get from our cache. It would make sense for SessionSecurityToken.ValidTo to equal TokenCacheItem.Expires surely? The +5 mins is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.samlsecuritytoken.validto%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)